# Function 'DEQUEUE_EMRKPF' doesn't dequeue

Tags: function, locking, abap, sap-erp

I want to dequeue a reservation in the db-table RKPF.

Why is this?

Actually I want to change a purchase requsition and therefore I need to execute the 'BAPI_PR_CHANGE'. I execute it twice to avoid failures. First as a test run and secondly as normal without the testrun-flag.

My problem is the following: during the first run (test run) it enqueues my reservation and the bapi leaves without dequeues my reservation, so I wanted to dequeue it by myself. but I failed

Does anybody know the solution of my problem?

Here my code to dequeue the reservation:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'DEQUEUE_EMRKPF'
 EXPORTING
   MODE_RKPF       = 'E'
   MANDT           = SY-MANDT
   RSNUM           = mv_rsnum
   _SCOPE          = '3'
   _SYNCHRON       = 'X'
   _COLLECT        = ' '
          .
```

Before giving me a answer check out these things I checked out before:

- I called the transaction SM12 and checked if my mv_rsnum is the same as in the table
- I didn't found any sy-subrc in the bapi
- I dequeued the banf which has this reservation number..

Comment: The original behaviour of the BAPI sounds like a bug. It should never ever be necessary to remove locks manually - in fact, this can be very dangerous. Have you tried to report it using http://service.sap.com/message?

Comment: i don't think so! It's pretty tricky. I searched again and debugged about one hour. 

I detected something: When I do this lock of a random reservation ( with se37->'enqueue_emrkpf','dequeue_emrkpf' ) by hand, it works. 

The only differents between the enqueue of the bapi and the enqueue I did, is that the Workflow-Number is not the same.

I have a constantly brainwash :S

Comment: Just to reiterate, you should NEVER have to fiddle with the enqueuing logic of a BAPI for yourself. Spending hours on trying to do so anyway is usually a good sign that you're looking for the problem in the wrong place.

Comment: It may be that the BAPI requires the current LUW to end before it releases the lock.  You could try to call FM BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK after the test run of your BAPI.

Comment: @ChristianLendel : I already checked sm12, AS I MENTIONED IN MY ANSWER ^^

I tried to dequeue the lock with the BAPI 'DEQUEUE_ALL'. All locks were closed, except the lock of my reservationnumber

Comment: Yes, but you didn´t wrote what the result was. Did you look up locks to your user or to all users? It sounds like SAP produces a lock on it without referring to the called user

Comment: @ChristianLendel i just looked up the locks to my user.

Comment: @ChristianLendel yes I checked it, "my" lock was the only on the table RKPF

Comment: Well, the next step is to remove the lock after using the test BAPI and see if you are able to use the BAPI the second time. If yes, look for a FM where you can dequeue locks that aren´t referred to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry guys. The Project must go on, therefore I deleted the code where I call the testrun of 'BAPI_PR_CHANGE'.**

This BAPI locked the table RKPF and at the end, it doesn't unlock the RKPF table.

But **THANKS TO ALL**, who wanted to help me!